# Python can't find nested package - ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python

I have a project structure like:

[image]

My **c.py** is like:

```
def test():
    print('sub_package')
```

My **b.py** is like:

```
def test():

    import sub_package.c

    print(sub_package.c.test())

    print('test')

#test()
```

I can directly run b.py and get the imported sub_package with no problem.

But if I run main.py, which is like:

```
import package.b

print(package.b.test())
```

Python would complain:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\test_package\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import package.b
  File "D:\test_package\package\b.py", line 10, in <module>
    test()
  File "D:\test_package\package\b.py", line 4, in test
    import sub_package.c
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sub_package'
```

It found package, but why the nested sub_package can't be found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python no longer supports implicit relative imports since the adoption of [PEP-328](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/)

In this case, you would need to use an explicit relative import in `b.py` like so:

```
from .sub_package import c

print(c.test())
```

Or you can use an absolute import instead like so:

```
from package.sub_package import c

print(c.test())
```